# Unfortunately, contacts has stopped Galaxy note 1 stock firmware

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-note, force-close

I'm running stock android version - 4.0.4 with baseband N7000DDLR1.
Received a minor update today in India(14.5MB) which said a performance update.

Everything worked fine after the update. However, my contacts and phone applications have stopped working. When I tried opening any of these apps I get "Unfortunately, contacts has stopped".

I have cleared the cache/data of contacts, contacts storage, phone. I even did a factory reset twice; removed the memory card and tried the same. Problem persists.

PS. I have never rooted / installed custom firmware.
Kindly help.

Comment: Came here from a Google search and thought that I would add that I have the same issue with an LG Optimus F3, Android version 4.1.2, software version P65910b. Factory reset does not fix the issue. I have submitted a warranty replacement to get a new phone; hopefully the new one is not affected.

Comment: It was some problem related to the motherboard. Samsung guys replaced the board.

Answer (score 1):

This is a firmware issue, and needs to be addressed by the manufacturer.

If you have done a factory reset, then you should contact the manufacturer and tell them that after the latest upgrade, the contact and phone app no longer work.

They *should* release a new upgrade to fix this issue.

Comment: gave it to samsung, and they gave it back - the phone wasn't switching on at all! I have given it again and I hope it isn't a major issue.